# Design Workflow that Emails People in Assigned To (Except for Created By)

Tags: list, workflow, email, tasks, task-list

We have a custom list that tracks work tasks in our department; we track our own work *and* use it to assign work/tasks to other colleagues.

I have a *people/groups* column called `AssignedTo` and need a workflow that will *only* send an email to the `AssignedTo` addresses when the person assigned is *not* the person who created it.

For example:

- if I create a task and assign it to myself then no email is sent to
  me.
- if my colleague creates a task and assigns it to me, then I will
  get an email (but she would not)
- if I create a task and assign myself
  plus three other people, the three other people would get an email
  (but I would not)

I've successfully created other workflows with emails but they were all generic; looking at my options I don't see how to make this happen and am hoping someone else has some experience that can guide me.  Thanks.

I am using SharePoint Designer and on version 2007 of Sharepoint.

Comment: Is this a custom workflow in VS2010 or are you limited to SharePoint Designer?

Comment: SharePoint Designer for 2007 (although I heard they will upgrade to 2010 at some point).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Before That i suggest one condition, Trim Assigned to Column (Group having Current User or Created by User).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am having trouble following the logic/approach. Where do you get "Workflow Context" optoin? I don't see that one ... are you on SPD 2007?

Comment: That was exactly the issue I was trying to figure out. This was very helpful. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, add a Wait step that sets the condition to:
>   Wait until Assigned To is not null   Then add a step for email:
>   Email Current Item:Assigned To message
>
> The trick is to make the workflow lookup the Assigned To value in the CURRENT ITEM.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/c8c34a45-b51f-42d9-a5c9-6b654e703c87

Comment: So - with this, I am able to email the folks who are in the `AssignedTo` column.  However, my questions is, that I want to email those folks in `AssignedTo` who are *not* the `Current Item:Created By`.  That is, I don't want to email myself when I assign myself a task.  I only want to email the other people I may have assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SP Designer, below is you solution:

In designer:

Create a LIST WORKFLOW based on the required list. 
From the ribbon, expand the drop down "Add Condition".
Select the option "If current item field equals value".

You will now have 3 clickable link

> field

**click this link & select your "AssignedTo" column**

> Equals

**click this link & select "does not contain"**

> Value

**click this link & select "user who created current item"**

> Finally put your Send email code which will be as below:

---

Add the ACTION "Send an Email" inside the above if block.

---

click the "These User" link & then select the "Workflow Lookup for a user" option.

---

Then in the new popup, select as below:

**Data source** : current Item

**Field From source** : AssignedTo

**Return as field** : Email Address

Comment: Hi and thanks!  This gets me close to the answer but not the last part: *if I create a task and assign myself plus three other people, the three other people would get an email (but I would not)* ... I am beginning to think it may not be possible to do in SPD2007.

Answer (score 0):

Thornomad.... In case you did not solve the answer to the last part of your post... "if I create a task and assign myself plus three other people, the three other people would get an email (but I would not) ... "  What I would do is take the AssignTo and using the string splitting actions in the SPD split them up so that I could test the email addresses. Too bad we don't have looping in SPD 2010. But you can manipulate strings. 
Hope this helps... (and others too if they are stuck on the same issue)