# How to send email to all the "Assigned to" users inside my sharepoint 2013 issue tracking list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, alert, issue-tracking

I have Issue Tracking list inside a team site on SharePoint 2013  . I need to know how I can force the system to send automatic emails to all the “Assigned To” users. So for example if someone create a new issue and assign it to  UserA , then an email should be send to him. After that if userA open the issue and assign it to UserB then userB should get another email.

I went to the list but on the “Share & Track” section there are only two options “Email a link & RSS”, but there is no alerts . While if I click on an issue there will be an alert image, but I need to define a general rule for the alerts inside the list “to send an email to the assign to user/s”.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me that you are looking for a SharePoint Designer workflow. What i can think of is this logic. When creating a workflow you get to choose the Start Options.

Selecting both

- *"Start workflow automatically when an item is created"* - should check for User A in the assigned to column when the items is created, and email him/her.
- *"Start workflow automatically when an item is changed"* - When the list item is updated with User B in the assigned to column it should email him/her instead, thanks to the option to start the workflow when the item is changed.

[image]

Maybe this thread can help you further:
[Design Workflow that Emails People in Assigned To (Except for Created By)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60622/design-workflow-that-emails-people-in-assigned-to-except-for-created-by)

Edit: I have not tested this myself.

Comment: Ok thanks for your email, i created a new workflow 2010 using SharePoint designer 2013, and i assign it to the issue tracking list. now i have noticed that this will automatically create a Task application inside my site collection. so is this what i need?

Comment: I did just try this in my offline virtual farm, and according to the logs in the workflow history it did send the email while creating and updating the listitem. ( I have not configured any mailsettings in my vm. ) About the task application, i cant really say i'm sure as i got very little experience with 2013.

Answer (score 3):

In your workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, once you set up the IF conditional, for the "then" condition, go to the "Action" menu and from drop down actions:

Step 1: Select Action "Send Email"

Step 2: click to edit the 'users' and click on the book icon of "To" field
[image]

Step 3: Choose "Workflow Lookup for a User..." and click on ADD
[image]

Step 4 and 5: From the "Lookup for Person or Group" window, choose the correct source in the source "Field from source"; in my case, the column titled "Dept. Stakeholder" Step 5: Choose "Return field as" field as 'Display Name' and click ok
[image]

End result should look like this:
[image]

The above steps created the correct algorithm engine to achieve this goal. In testing phase, I switched users for an assignment multiple times in the "Department Stakeholder" field - which is same as your "Assigned To" in the Document Library. As long as the primary parameters to trigger the workflow met, SP activated the workflow and send out the email.